# Replacing '>' with jQuery while preserving all HTML

Tags: jquery, html, function, replace

I am trying to replace a ">" in a string in jQuery but the problem I'm having is that I need to preserve the HTML. Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
<div class="link">
    <a href="#">
        <span>Test ></span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <span>Test 2 ></span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <span>Test 3 ></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

If I use this code:

```
$(".link").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    text = text.replace(/>/g,'/');
    $(this).text(text);
});
```

It strips the `<span>` tags out of the HTML since it's replacing it with text.

If I use this code:

```
$(".link").each(function() {
    var html = $(this).html();
    html = html.replace(/>/g,'/');
    $(this).html(html);
});
```

It replaces the closing tags of the span and anchor tags since they are technically `>` as well. I'm trying to find a way to just replace the `>`'s that are text as opposed to all instance of it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum's suggestion also fixes your issue, if you ensure the `>`'s are escaped, all you'd have to do is replace the escaped version `&gt;`, so then you could just use the `$(this).html();` version of you example code snippets.

Comment: you should use &gt; instead of >. > is for html tags. Your html is invalid as Benjamin says

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum are you sure about that?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum what spec that's a guide.

Comment: @Musa Wow man, you're right. The spec only forbids `<` in section 4.5, probably because a `>` isn't supposed to be ambiguous. I just read that section 5 times, both in HTML5 and HTML4.01, Thanks for teaching me something :) This **HTML OP is using is valid!** It passes W3C validation and I manually went through elements in the document and parsed them using the spec.

Comment: @user1321471, I'm actually unable to edit the HTML. This is on the framework of a Volusion store which generates everything dynamically. Using &gt would make my life much easier but unfortunately it's all dynamically generated and doesn't allow me the option to edit those string characters. But I hear ya!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:-

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k65td/)

```
$(".link a span").each(function () {
    var text = $(this).text(function (_, oldVal) {
        return oldVal.replace(/>/g, '/')
    });
});
```

This will work for html with `>` as well as `&gt;`

```
<div class="link"> <a href="#">
        <span>Test &gt;</span>
    </a>
 <a href="#">
        <span>Test 2 &gt;</span>
    </a>
 <a href="#">
        <span>Test 3 &gt;</span>
    </a>

</div>
```

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'replace' ` , Chrome 27, Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

You could just search the actual text that have the `>` instead of the whole html.

```
$(".link span").contents().each(function() {
    var text = this.nodeValue;
    text = text.replace(/>/g,'/');
    this.nodeValue = text;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L5m24/

Answer (score 0):

Just assign this HTML to `innerHTML` of a temporary element, and then read `innerHTML` of this temporary element, and you'll get valid HTML code with invalid angle bracket converted to HTML entity. You can then replace the `&gt;` entity instead of `>` character.

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XrYVk/)

Answer (score 0):

This simple function will, recursively, remove all `>` or `&gt;` from **any text element** it finds down the road:

```
function removeAllGt(element) {
    $(element).contents().each(function () {
        if (this.nodeType == 3) {
            this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(/>/g, '/');
        } else {
            removeAllGt(this);
        }
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
$(".link").each(function () {
    removeAllGt(this);
});
```

[**Demo fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/XRRdU/).